# How can I use OR in an if statement?

Tags: php, mysql

my if-statement is not working in the way I wish it. Maybe you can help me. I wish that if in mySQL database `cat` is empty OR `dog` is empty, it should echo `animal missing`.

```
if (empty($row['cat']) || empty($row['dog'])) {
    echo "animal missing";
}
```

What happens now is: if `cat` AND `dog` is empty -> echo `animal missing`, if `cat` is not empty and `dog` is empty -> echo `animal missing` BUT if `cat` is empty and `dog` is not empty -> echo nothing. I do not understand that...

Comment: Correct operator I believe is `||`, Using OR is for SQL not for PHP, Stand corrected by jonbaldie. Best practice to use the operators for php though.

Comment: `or` is also valid in PHP.

Comment: I found out that `empty($row['cat'])` is not working, although it is empty. But it is really empty in the database :( Only  `empty($row['dog'])` is working

Comment: What do you mean by empty in mysql? a `NULL` value or a string of length zero?

Comment: try var_dump($row); is it correct what you expected?

Comment: If you are checking for missing values in the database I would use a switch statement to go through the list of types of animals to check rather than an if statement but that's just me.

Comment: with var_dump I get  `["cat"]=> string(1) " " [20]=> string(1) " "` and  `["dog"]=> string(0) "" [29]=> string(0) ""`

Comment: @mynawaz: Well in my database It is an empty field with no value. Actually this is all I need

Comment: `" "` is not an empty string, it's a string with one space character. So empty logically returns false.

Comment: @jarla, The field cat is not an empty string, but a string of length 1. Eithet change in db or use trim in php

Comment: Thank you! With your help I found the mistake. This is the select box I used to create the empty value: `<option value=' '>--</option>` so it had to be `<option value=''>--</option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What values do $row['dog'] and $row['cat'] hold if they're not considered "empty"?

In your var_dump it seems that you have just a whitespace character in one of them. Try trimming the whitespace before checking if they really are empty:

```
if(empty(trim($row['cat'])) || empty(trim($row['dog']))) {
    echo "animal missing";
}
```

What empty(mixed $var) does:

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.
>   – http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get this: Just use thi

```
if (!empty($row['cat']) AND !empty($row['dog'])) {

}
else
{
 echo "animal missing";
}
```